# Multicolum Table

Tags: tables, multicol

I am new to latex and i would like to draw this table shown in the picture.

Any help is highly[image] appreciated

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
  Characteristics & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Where?} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Who?} & Physical          Immersion? & Mental Immersion? & Computer Required? & Interactive?\\
\hline
Media & Real & Real & Virtual & Me & We & & & & \\
& World & World & World & & & & & & \\
& Here & There & & & & & & & \\
VR & Real & Real & Virtual & Me & We & & & & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please poste the code that you already have, so not every helping reader would need to type that all again.

Comment: \begin{landscape}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \toprule
     Characteristics & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Where?} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Who?} & Physical Immersion? & Mental Immersion? & Computer Required? & Interactive?\\
     \midrule
      &  &  &  &  &  & & & & \\
      Media & Real & Real & Virtual & Me & We & & & & \\
      & World & World & World & & & & & & \\
      & Here & There & & & & & & & \\
      &  &  &  &  &  & & & & \\
      VR &  &  & $\ding{51}$ &  &  & & & & \\
      &  &  &  &  &  & & & & \\
  
      \end{tabular}
      \end{landscape}

Answer (score 1):

may be this can be used as a first hint:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2\\
3 & {\cellcolor{gray}X}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit 1: A second approach via `tabularx` and use of `X` columns

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.7}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{Gray}\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{This is a table I am using}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{1.1\textwidth}{|L|Y|Y|a|Y|a|Y|Y|a|Y|Y|Y|a|Y|}\hline
Characteristics & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Where} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Who?} & 
 \multicolumn{2}{G|}{Physical immersion?} & 
 \multicolumn{2}{G|}{Mental imersion} & 
 \multicolumn{2}{G|}{Computer required?} & 
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Interactive?} \\ \hline
\rowcolor{white}
MEDIA & Real world here & Real word there& Virtual world & Me & We & Yes & No & Yes & No& Yes & No
& Yes & No \\ \hline
Virtual reality &x & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
Augmented \newline reality & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
Telepresences &x & & & &x & & & & & & & & \\\hline
Teleoperation &x & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
Novel & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
Interactive \newline fiction &x & & x& & x& & & & & & & & \\\hline
Online chat & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
Live TV \newline documentary & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
TV situation \newline Comdy & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
Cyberspace & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is an attempt, where several column types were defined for `m` type. In particular, `a` and `u` types are for gray columns.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{gray}\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.6cm}}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.6cm}}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}}
\newcolumntype{u}{>{\columncolor{gray}\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{This is a table I am using}
\centering
\begin{tabular}
{|l|U|U|u|b|a|b|b|a|b|b|b|a|b|}\hline
Characteristics & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Where} &
 \multicolumn{2}{G|}{Who?} & 
 \multicolumn{2}{G|}{Physical immersion?} & 
 \multicolumn{2}{G|}{Mental imersion} & 
 \multicolumn{2}{G|}{Computer required?} & 
 \multicolumn{2}{G|}{Interactive?} \\ \hline
\rowcolor{white}
MEDIA & Real world here & Real word there& Virtual world & Me & We & Yes & No & Yes & No& Yes & No
& Yes & No \\ \hline
Virtual reality &x & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
Augmented reality & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
Telepresences &x & & & &x & & & & & & & & \\\hline
Teleoperation &x & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
Novel & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
Interactive fiction &x & & x& & x& & & & & & & & \\\hline
Online chat & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
Live TV documentary & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
TV situation Comdy & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
Cyberspace & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```