# Table multicolumn branched columns

Tags: tables

[image: generate table]
I would like to generate table exactly with same pattern. I am trying from last few hrs not able to get it correct any one could

plz help me ASAP thanking you

Comment: See the similar case http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170495/multicolum-table?rq=1

Comment: Welcome! Please always include a minimum working example in your questions. In this case, the code for a minimal document with the code for the table you've got so far would be an invaluable starting point for those trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{This is a table }
\centering
\begin{tabular}
{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
N & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{One} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Two} &
 \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Three}  \\ \hline
1 &  & & & & & & & &   \\\hline
2 &  & & & & & & & &  \\\hline
3 &  & & & & & & & &  \\\hline
4 &  & & & & & & & &  \\\hline
5 &  & & & & & & & &  \\\hline
6 &  & & & & & & & &  \\\hline
7 &  & & & & & & & &  \\\hline
8 &  & & & & & & & &  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
{} &\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}\\
\hline
1 &&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
2 &&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
3 &&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
4 &&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
5 &&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
6 &&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
7 &&&&&&&&&\\\hline
8 &&&&&&&&&\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: emptytbl]